Struggling to link a TWebLabelLink
I want to link to a LinkedIn profile via a TWebLabelLink but cannot find a property that I can edit to link it to the hyperlink. I know it is not a Windows application, so ShellAPI unit won't work.
I tried to link it via ShellExecute with the following OnClick code:
uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, JS, Web, WEBLib.Graphics, WEBLib.Controls,
  WEBLib.Forms, WEBLib.Dialogs, Windows,Vcl.StdCtrls, WEBLib.StdCtrls, WEBLib.ExtCtrls,
    Messages,  Variants,  Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, Vcl.Imaging.pngimage,ShellAPI;


procedure ShellOpen(const Url: string; const Params: string = '');
begin
  ShellAPI.ShellExecute(0, 'Open', PChar(Url), PChar(Params), nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
end;

procedure TfrmMain.WebLinkLabel1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShellOpen('https://www.linkedin.com/company/companyname/');
end;

end.

The error I was met with is:

cannot find unit "ShellAPI"

I assume it is due to the application not being a Windows application.

With the TWebLabelLink component, you can actually simply add a hyperlink <a> tag into the Caption of the component.
So let's say that you want the label to say "Click here to go to LinkedIn", then you can simply write the following into the Caption of the component:
Click <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/companyname/">here</a> to go to LinkedIn


But if you want more control over what happens with a click, then you can add an OnClick event to the component and navigate to a URL using the following code:
Application.Navigate('www.example.com', TNavigationTarget.ntBlank);

The above code will open the link in a new tab, if you want to open it in the current tab, then use:
Application.Navigate('www.example.com', TNavigationTarget.ntPage);

